# Automatically boot Grub into OSX

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, macosx, grub-efi

Is there a way to boot automatically into OSX, bypassing the GRUB menu in Ubuntu 16? Currently when I boot up, the screen looks something like

```
Boot into Ubuntu 16.04
Boot into Mac OSX El Capitan
Advanced Options for Ubuntu
```

Is there any way to boot into OSX and return to the GRUB menu if I hold a certain key? Thanks so much!